# Ionic release build with phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner failed

Tags: plugins, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

Since I have installed the plugin `phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner` im not able to build a android release version

```
ionic build android --release
```

A normal development build is possible without some problems.

```
ionic build android
```

I neither have some trouble to build a release without the barcode scanner plugin. But if i add the plugin and build release i get the following error:

```
\platforms\android\res\values-ar\strings.xml:64: Error: "menu_settings" is translated here but not found in default locale [ExtraTranslation]
  <string name="menu_settings">???????</string>
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-bg\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-ca\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-cs\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-da\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-de\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-el\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-es\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-eu\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-fi\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-fr\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-he\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-hi\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-hu\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-id\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-it\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-iw\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-ja\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-ko\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-nl\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-pl\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-pt\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-ru\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-sk\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-sl\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-sv\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-tr\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-zh-rCN\strings.xml:64: Also translated here
    D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\res\values-zh-rTW\strings.xml:64: Also translated here

   Explanation for issues of type "ExtraTranslation":
   If a string appears in a specific language translation file, but there is
   no corresponding string in the default locale, then this string is probably
   unused. (It's technically possible that your application is only intended
   to run in a specific locale, but it's still a good idea to provide a
   fallback.).

   Note that these strings can lead to crashes if the string is looked up on
   any locale not providing a translation, so it's important to clean them
   up.

5 errors, 0 warnings
 FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 9.482 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':lintVitalRelease'.
> Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
...

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildRelease -b D:\Git\mobile\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\ss\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. You have to override `build.gradle`. Just run this comand and it works

```
echo 'android { lintOptions { checkReleaseBuilds false } }' >> platforms/android/build-extras.gradle
```